# no sql read and write intensive bigdata table

Tags: nosql, bigdata

I am having 10 different queries and a total of 40 columns.
Looking for solutions in available Big data noSQL data bases  that will  perform read and write intensive jobs (multiple queries  with SLA).

Tried with HBase but its fast only for rowkey (scan) search ,for other queries  (not running on row key) query response time is quite high.Making data duplication with different row keys is the only option for quick response but for 10 queries making 10 different tables is not a good idea.

Please suggest the alternatives.

Comment: What sort of predicates are in the queries, what sort of data scale are you talking, and how fast is fast enough, how much resource will you stump up. (nb apologies for down/up votes, buttons badly placed for ipad)

Comment: I have to extract the records in 2-3 sec (thats what currrent system Oracle is providing) and the number of records varies from thousands to tens of thousands or even more

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Druid](http://druid.io/)? It is inspired on [Dremel](https://research.google.com/pubs/pub36632.html), precursor of [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).

From the [documentation](http://druid.io/docs/0.10.0/design/design.html):

> **Druid** is a good fit for products that require **real-time data ingestion** of a single, large data stream. Especially if you are targeting **no-downtime operation** and are building your product on top of a time-oriented summarization of the incoming data stream. When talking about query speed it is important to clarify what "fast" means: with Druid it is entirely within the realm of possibility (we have done it) to achieve queries that run ***in less than a second across trillions of rows of data.***